# Why such an error occurs when using pip install to install the package？

Tags: python, pycharm

`WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (d:\python_3.9.7\lib\site-packages)` is displayed during the installation process

why does this appear？

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to files names with the '~' prefix in site-packages. Please remove those files / folders. It will solve your problem.

You can list them (linux, mac) with

```
ls -a /xx/xx/xx/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages | grep "^~"
```

on windows I would strongly recommend the linux subsystem for windows for this kind of actions. But of course this can also be done via the explorer or the cmd

Then remove files/folders prefixed by '~'.